# How do I make persistent tcp-keepalive setting in Debian

Tags: debian, configuration, tcp

I have been looking at tcp-keepalive as a possible solution for network inactivity. As shared in -

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

specifically this part -

> Preventing disconnection due to network inactivity

Mine are actually ISP issues but do want to keep it bare minimum from my side.

I have done and changed -

```
  # echo 600 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time

  # echo 60 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl

  # echo 20 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes
```

but as shared these are just for this session. Is there a persistent solution for this ?

Answer (score 5):

You have a persistent parameters ,and you can add the following lines to your `/etc/sysctl.conf` :

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 600
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 20
```

Then type:

```
# sysctl -p
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern Linux systems allow you to use configuration fragments in `/etc/sysctl.d`.  Add a file like `50-keepalive.conf` in this directory.  Add the appropriate systemctl values.

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 600
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 20
```

These values will be set on the next reboot.  Make sure your interval is less than the timeout period of any firewall you are passing through.

Use the command `man sysctl` to get information on how to use sysctl to check and modify your configuration.